# Should I use vue-resource on Vuex actions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource, vuex

I am developing a webapp where it fetches airports from back end.  I am also using Vuex to share states and data. My question is should I load the airports in my VueX actions or on my vue instance method then call the action that dispatches only the event

Example

```
// ajax from vuex actions
export const loadAirports = ({dispatch})=>{
    //load data via vue-resource
    dispatch("SET_AIRPORTS",data);
}
```

or

```
//action
export const setAirports(({dispatch},airports) =>{
   dispatch("SET_AIRPORTS",airports);
}

new Vue({
    ready(){
        //load data view-resource

        this.setAirports(data); 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutations should always be synchronous.  But it's fine to do your ajax in actions, in fact that is how it is done in many of the [official examples](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/master/examples/shopping-cart/vuex/actions.js).  I would do

```
import {loadAirports} from './actions.js'

new Vue({
  vuex:{
    actions: {
      loadAirports
    },
    getters: {
      airports: state => state.airports
    }
  },
  ready(){
    this.loadAirports();
  }
});
```